# Read a text file and store it in the hashmap

Tags: hashmap

I am reading a file called Expenses.txt...I want to store it in a hashmap with repeated entries of items

The text file contains data on several lines, where each line (a record) consists of two fields: category name (a string), and its value (a number). For example, the file below shows expenses by category.

**Input**

Expenses.txt

cosmetics   100.00
medicines   120.00
cosmetics   50.00
books       250.00
medicines   80.00
medicines   100.00

program should generate a Summary report showing the sums and averages by category, sorted by category. The summary should be displayed on the console. The program should prompt the user and read in the name of the input file.

For example, for the above data, the summary will be:

**output**

Category    Total       Average

books       $250        $250.00
medicines   $300.00         $100.00
cosmetics   $150.00         $75.00

a) The first field is a string and the second field is a floating point number.

b) The number of records for each category may vary. For example, in the above example, there are 2 records for cosmetics, 3 for medicines and 1 for books.

c) The total number of records (lines) may vary. Do not limit them to any fixed number.

d) The records are not in any sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the language you are using, but I would recommend you using some kind of structure of tuple to save in the hashmap. You can read each line, split each of them in two (for the label and the value), and check if the label is already in the hashmap. If it is, just increment by one the number of units, as well as summing the coast.
At the end, just do a hashmap transversal and print all the values needed.